# Select manual em repositório usando Spring?

Tags: spring, select, rest, repository

Olá, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer um select dentro do `Repository`, estou usando `Spring` e `REST`, preciso retornar todas as entidades que possuem outra entidade, pegaria elas pelo id, e preciso alimentar uma chamada ajax com ela, então precisaria de um array json. Se alguém puder ajudar, ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, crio métodos com nomes específicos, como esse:

```
List<Answer> findByQuestionIdAndDeadIsFalse(String questionId);
```

Criei dentro do `Repository` e chamo ele, fazendo uma injeção de dependência no lugar em que preciso, no meu caso no `Controller`.